# taking fields out of a multiple Array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to take out files out of an Array that defined like this:

> $arr[$j][$player_number]['field_name'];

I have 2 fields in the array : names and rating. The output when I'm printing the array is :

```
Array ( [$j] => Array ( [names] => "some name" [rating] => "some number" ))
```

My problem is that I can't take the fields "names" and "rating" at the same loop when I'm doing "for each". When I'm doing it separately - it works but I can't sort it in a table normally.
I know that I have to use the "list" in some way, I tried to execute it, but without success.

What I'm doing is :

> 

```
function get_array_column($array, $column)
    {
        $ret = array();
        foreach ($array as $row) $ret[] = $row[$column];
        return $ret;
    }
    for($i=1;$i<=$num_groups;$i++)
    {   
        $a = array();
        $a = get_array_column($arr[$i],'names');
        foreach ($a as $value)
           {
             echo $value;
           }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code that you have written so far, as it is difficult to understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @i-alarm-edalien The code was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you defined your array as

```
[0] => Array ( [name] => name0 
[fieldname] => fieldname0 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => name1 [fieldname] => fieldname1 )

foreach ($arr as $key){

echo $key['names'];

echo $key['ratings'];

}
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a three dimensional array.

1. dimension indicated by $j
2. dimension indicated by $player_number
3. dimension indicated by $field_name

Maybe you want something like this:
An array which is indicated by the number of the player
`$array[$player_number]`

In this array you can add stdClass objects, which contain the name and the rating of the player. The code could look like this

```
//create players array
$players = array();
//create a player
$player = new stdClass();
$player->number = 342;
$player->name = "Matt Click";
$player->rating = 13;
// add a player to the players array
$players[$player->number] = $player;
... // some code
// foreach through the players
foreach ($players as $player)
{
    echo "Name: ".$player->name." rating:".$player->rating."\n";
}
```

Comment: Maybe it will work, but it's not what I'm searching. The array is ready and the only thing that I'm trying to do is to output 2 fields at the same loop. And the field_name is not a variable (without $), there are only 2 fields each array - names and rating.

Comment: Please tell me again how your array is looking like, cause `$arr[$j][$player_number]['field_name'];` means something else as you are saying.